# Name of orthogonal/unitary matrix decomposition?

Tags: matrix-decomposition, orthogonal-matrices

Suppose we have an orthogonal/unitary matrix $T$ of even dimension. Then we can decompose it into:
$$
T = \begin{bmatrix}
  U_1 & 0 \\
  0 & U_2
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
  R & -\sqrt{I-R^2} \\
  \sqrt{I-R^2} & R
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
  V_1 & 0 \\
  0 & V_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $U_1$, $U_2$, $V_1$, and $V_2$ are orthogonal/unitary matrices half the size of $T$, and $R$ is diagonal.

Does this decomposition have a name? Anything useful known about it?

Comment: it looks like something like polar-decomposition "on both sides" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition
The matrix in the middle would be the "rotation" and the ones on the sides would be "scaling".